# updating subdocument array in mongoose express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I have a schema, which is like this:

```
const playerSchema = new Schema(
      {
        user: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'user'
        },
        paid : {type: Boolean, default: false}
      }
    )
const tournamentSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    player:[ playerSchema])
```

so in the tournament model i get this as return:

```
{
 "_id": "5fbf3afe1ecd92296c746db6",
 "name": "1st Testing Tournament",
 "player": [
        {
            "paid": false,
            "_id": "5fbf3cfe6347784028da8181",
            "user": "5fbf3b4c1ecd92296c746dcd"
        }
    ]}
```

in the API I will have only the user ID and the tournament ID. I want to update `paid` in `players` array from false to true. Here is what I tried:

```
exports.put_confirmPayment= async(req, res)=>{
    const uid = req.params.user_id
    const tid = req.params.tid
    const findData= {"_id": tid, "player.user": uid  }
    const changeData = {"player.$.paid": "true"}
    try {
        await Tournament.findOneAndUpdate( findData, {$set: {changeData}} )
        const tDB = await Tournament.findById(tid)
        res.status(200).json(tDB)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(500).json(error.message)
    }
}
```

Where I am going wrong? and what should my approach be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- convert string id from string to object type using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`
- change "true" string to boolean true
- return updated result using `returnOriginal: false`, or `new: true` both will return new updated result
- have removed extra constant variables, don't create too much variables

```
exports.put_confirmPayment = async(req, res) => {

    try {
        const tDB = await Tournament.findOneAndUpdate(
          { 
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.tid), 
            "player.user": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.user_id) 
          }, 
          { $set: { "player.$.paid": true } },
          { returnOriginal: false }
        );
        res.status(200).json(tDB);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json(error.message);
    }

}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DJidleWrRum)

> For more information refer mongoose [findoneandupdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) documentation.